# how to make a simple raster plot with one or more event traces

Tags: plot, raster

Can anyone recommend a simple way to make a raster plot of events in Matlab?
Rather than giving me a binary read out of all the time points in a range, the recording data I generate gives me the timepoints that specific events occur at , but not the timepoints in between. Because of this, I end up with vectors of events for the same time period but with different lengths.
For example, for a 10 second period (t = 1:10), two simultaneous recordings will have event vectors like this:

V1 = [2 2.1 2.6 3.3 4 5 6 6.1 7]
V2 = [1 5 7.1]

How do I plot these as vertical hash marks at each one of the event time points? I'm looking to make a plot that looks something like this:

V1                         ||  |    |  |       ||        |
V2  |                 |                  |

Comment: Which programing language will you use? It is difficult to answer without example code or data here. You can edit your post, so please add examples if you have.

Comment: ah yes, sorry - Matlab. question has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Because I cannot use Matlab now, I don’t have much confidence it’s actuaaly works. I mean, array shape may not appropriate.

```
num_spikes = length(V1)
plot([V1; V1], [ones(1, num_spikes); ones(1, num_spikes) + 1], ‘k’)
```